# Encryption and Decryption in java similar to C#

Tags: java, encryption

I have a code in C# which is used for encryption and decryption, i have written a code in java using the same key and initial vector used in c# but getting IV length should be 8 bytes

C# Code :

```
 public string EncryptString(string ClearText)
{

   byte[] clearTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ClearText);

   System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm rijn = 
   SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    byte[] rgbIV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ryojvlzmdalyglrj");
    byte[] key = 
    Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hcxilkqbbhczfeultgbskdmaunivmfuo");
    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rijn.CreateEncryptor(key, rgbIV),
    CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    cs.Write(clearTextBytes, 0, clearTextBytes.Length);

    cs.Close();

    return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
}
```

Java Code:

```
public String encryptText(String cipherText) throws Exception {

    String plainKey = "hcxilkqbbhczfeultgbskdmaunivmfuo";
    String plainIV = "ryojvlzmdalyglrj";

    KeySpec ks = new  DESKeySpec(plainKey.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES").generateSecret(ks);

    IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(plainIV.getBytes());

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivspec);
    byte[] decoded = cipher.doFinal(cipherText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    return new Base64().encodeToString(decoded);
}
```

I have to use the same key and initial vector, do i have to use another algorithm ??

I am stuck with the above for more than a day.

Comment: Yes, you have to use another algorithm. What made you think the C# code is using `DES`?

Comment: @Kayaman i even tried with AES but did not get what is required, can you guide me which algorithm should i use to achieve the above ??

Comment: Think of me more as a signpost and not a guide. The C# code uses AES.

Comment: Kayaman is right, you need to use  `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding`, IV should have length of the  block (128 bit=16 bytes).

Comment: well thanx alot for suggesting, this time AES worked.